# Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am experimenting with the codes from [Setting location.hash in frames.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642947/setting-location-hash-in-frames) It works well in IE and FF, but Chrome throws the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Can anybody explain why only Chrome thorws this error? Thanks.

Comment: what is your code? when i open the console and type `document.location.hash = "works"` it seems fine

Comment: yup, it works well inside console. It get wrong if you run the .html.

Comment: can you put up an example? I have it working fine: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
 document.location.hash = "works";
  </script>
</head>
<body >
 <script>
 document.writeln(document.location.hash);
 </script>
</body>
</html>`
I'm guessing you've misspelled something.

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
window.location.href = "welcome.htm";
```